# Mathematical formulas in column

Tags: equations, align

How do I write the following formula in this format?

[image]

Comment: The picture looks awful. But you are probably looking for the `align` environment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Aligning%20equations%20with%20amsmath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you try so far? As skeleton for your equations can serve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{aligned}
S(n) & \leqslant 2^{\lceil \log n\rceil+1} -1   \\  
     & < 2  ...                                 \\
     & =    ...                                 \\
     & \leqslant 4\cdot 2^{\floor \log n\rfloor} \\
     & \leqslant 4n 
\end{aligned}    
    \]
\end{document}
```

Missing math expression (marked by `...`) I left to you.

[image]

**Edit:**
corrected  equation as sugdested by @Bernard (`\lceill` and `\rceill` in fourth equation line are replaced by `\lfloor` and `\rfloor` respectively).

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to start with a skeleton, I'm new here :-/ sorry and thanks for the answer

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo, you need to make yourself more familiar with LaTeX. Writing math should be basic to use LaTeX ;-). SO, for start see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics. Replacing`...` with correct math expression should not be a big deal. You for example already have complete rewrite the first line of your equation.

Comment: Thank you :-D I will follow this link

Comment: @Zarko: In the last but one equation, I think you should use `\lfloor\log n\rfloor`.

Comment: @Bernard, you are right. The image is not the best quality and I overlooked this as well didn't check math validity ... I will correct asap.

Comment: @Zarko sorry for the quality of the photo, unfortunately, a lot of sites is very bad with accessibility for the dyslexia font. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

This question is not LaTeX specific. So, there is another answer. If you are using TeX with Unicode math (for example OpTeX), then you can write:

```
$$\eqalign{
   S(n) & ⩽ 2^{⌈\log n⌉+1} - 1 \cr
        & < 2 ⋅ 2^{⌈\log n⌉} \cr
        & = 4 ⋅ 2^{⌈\log n⌉-1} \cr
        & ⩽ 4 ⋅ 2^{⌊\log n⌋} \cr
        & ⩽ 4n
}
$$
\bye
```